# How do I know the total number of files after splitting in Linux Split

Tags: linux, split, du

I know that `Linux Split` can Split large files by file size in the following way, and the result is in the form of a `numeric suffix`

```
split -b 1G -d filepath suffix"

# result
suffix01  suffix02 ...
```

But I would like to be able to get the total split result in it and use it for the split file, say `five files`, and I would like the result to be as follows

```
suffix5-01  suffix5-02 suffix5-03 suffix5-04 suffix5-05
```

While you can use other methods like `du` to get the total file size, I don't know if split is based on the size `du` gets, and that's not an elegant way to do it.

Therefore, is there a perfect solution to achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with **GNU Parallel**.

First make a 10MB file to work with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=10240 count=1024 > data.bin
```

Now split into 1MB chunks, naming each chunk `suffix{TOTALCHUNKS}-{CHUNKNUMBER}`

```
parallel --recend '' --plus --pipepart --block 1M cat \> suffix{##}-{#} :::: data.bin
```

**Result**

```
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-1
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-2
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-3
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-4
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-5
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-6
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-7
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-8
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-9
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   1048576  9 Aug 16:57 suffix10-10
```

Notes:

- You need `--recend ''` to stop **GNU Parallel** trying to split your file on linefeeds
- You need `--plus` so that `{##}` is set to the total number of jobs
- You need `--pipepart` to make it faster on seekable files - if your file is not seekable, use `--pipe` instead
- {##} means *the total number of chunks*
- {#} means *the current chunk number*

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the splitted files with the format you specified, you could use this:

```
split -b 1G -d filepath suffix-
```

Then, to get the number of splitted files:

```
ls | grep suffix- | wc -l
```

If you want to get the size of each splitted file:

```
for i in $(find . -name 'suffix-*'); do
  echo "$i has size: $(stat --format '%s' $i)B"
done
```

This will give you the size of each file expressed in bytes. To print the result in KB:

```
for i in $(find . -name 'suffix-*'); do
  echo "$i has size: $(expr $(stat --format '%s' $i) / 1024)KB"
done
```

Also, if you want the output to be sorted and to cut the characters './' from result, you can use:

```
for i in $(find . -name 'suffix-*'); do
  echo "$i has size: $(expr $(stat --format '%s' $i) / 1024)KB"
done | sort | cut -c3-
```